# My HP Pavilion DV6 Notebook has USB 3.0 ports or not?

Tags: laptop, usb

My laptop HP Pavilion DV6 has no signs of "ss", "2.0", or "3.0". It has all ports of USB in Black/grey tongue.

Please check the image of my device manager. Tell me it has USB 3.0 port or not.

[image: click here to view the snap]

i checked it with "HP Support Assistant", i installed "HP Support Assistant", it showed me

MY PC Product name: HP Pavilion Notebook Serial number: Product number: A3x35UA#ABA click here to view image

i pasted A3x35UA#ABA in google search engine and got model name "HP Pavilion dv6-6172nr" , i searched "HP Pavilion dv6-6172nr" specification, i found it has 2 USB Port 2.0 and 2 USB Port 3.0 . https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03068259

But again problem is: When i connect my Kingston 3.0 usb in all 4 usb ports, which are in Black/Grey color but not Blue, my system said:"It can perform faster, if it is connected with Super Speed 3.0 ports"

**1)** **but why ? if my laptop have 3.0 why this message appear while connecting 3.0 usb in ports....**

**2)** IF my laptop have USB Ports 3.0 ports, i have 4 ports, my question is >>> which are 2.0 and 3.0 ?

Comment: does it have "ss" printed anywhere?

Comment: What's the _specific_ model number?

Comment: i purchased used product from local shop...

Comment: HP Pavilion dv6-6172nr , i think, "HP Support Assistant" toll showed me, there no ss sign, no 3.0 or 2.0 sign, all ports tongue are in black color...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your screenshot and the [HP Pavilion DV6 specifications](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03127146), your laptop has USB 3.0 ports. According to the specs, there are two USB 3.0 and two USB 2.0 ports.

Also, according to [HP Pavilion dv6 Notebook PC Maintenance and Service Guide](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02842252.pdf), the USB 3.0 ports are located on the left side (see page 17) while the ordinary USB 2.0 ports are on the right side (see page 18).

Of course, there were manuals on HP website. If this is not the correct manual, [find yours](https://support.hp.com/us-en/products/laptops/pavilion-notebooks/) using your product serial number.

Answer (score -1):

Next time, check your [product specifications](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/product/hp-pavilion-dv6-6b00-entertainment-notebook-pc-series/5145688/model/5205567/document/c03135715):

- 1 VGA
- 2 headphone-out
- 1 microphone-in
- 2 USB 2.0
- 2 USB 3.0
- 1 RJ45